# UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Hey guys I'm trying to let users rotate and scale the size of `UIImageView` that I add programmatically but for some reason my gesture recognizers aren't working. To add the `UIImageView` I use a UITapGesture which I set up through the storyboard which works fine. Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)addUIImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:_Image];
        NSLog(@"Screen tapped");
        UIImageView *ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]];

        [ImageView setCenter:[sender locationInView:_Image]];
        ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        ImageView.multipleTouchEnabled =  YES;

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resizeImage:)];
        [ImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImage:)];
        [ImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture];

        [self.Image addSubview:ImageView];
}
```

and then for the pinch and rotate gestures I have:

```
- (void)resizeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

and

```
-(void)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

anyone know what's wrong and why my gestures won't work?

Comment: It should work? What is the NSLog of the pinchGesture? And are you making the gestures correctly, if you are testing in simulator?

Comment: I just put NSLog's into the pinch and rotate gestures to see if they're even being called, which they're not for whatever reason. In the simulator I'm using the alt/option button to make the gestures. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM. The UIImageView I'm using is only 100x100 and it was too hard to zoom in on the simulator using such a small image so you ended up being right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView was too small to properly pinch and rotate on simulator.